# Confusion about inverse trignometry.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

So for $arctan(tan(2))$, because the graph is only defined on $(\frac{\pi}2<x<\frac{\pi}2)$, how is it possible that the answer is defined and not 2.

Comment: Please click the accepted answer button for answers you have found to answer your question.  Don't leave so many questions of your without a marked answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sin(x)=\sin(x\pm2\pi), \cos(x)=\cos(x\pm2\pi), \tan(x)=\tan(x\pm\pi)$

Therefore:

$\arctan(\tan(2))=\arctan(\tan(2-\pi)$

Now you have $-\frac {\pi} 2<2-\pi<\frac {\pi} 2$

Comment: Does that mean the domain for arcsin(sin(x)) arccos(cos(x)) and arctan(tan(x)) is actually infinite?

Comment: Of course.  We use these restrictions to make things simpler because the function repeats itself after $\frac {\pi} 2$.  Since it repeats, there isn't much special to notice.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot